# Sending Email With Lua

Tags: email, lua, smtp

How would you send an email using Lua?
The team I'm working with have a mail server, is that of any relevance?
Here is the code I'm using:

```
function send_email (email_to, email_subject, email_message)
  local SMTP_SERVER = "mail.server.com"
  local SMTP_AUTH_USER = "mail@domain.com"
  local SMTP_AUTH_PW = "password"
  local SMTP_PORT = "587"
  local USER_SENDING = "mail@domain.com"

  local smtp = require("socket.smtp")
  local rcpt = {email_to}
  local mesgt = {
    headers = {
      to = email_to,
      from = USER_SENDING,
      subject = email_subject
    },
      body = email_message
  }
  local r, e = smtp.send{
    from  = USER_SENDING,
    rcpt  = rcpt,
    source  = smtp.message(mesgt),
    server = SMTP_SERVER,
    port = SMTP_PORT,
    user = SMTP_AUTH_USER,
    password = SMTP_AUTH_PW
  }
end
```

Comment: Is it not working? Do you `print(r, e)`? Is there some error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [LuaSocket SMTP](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/smtp.html) API.

Your example looks correct, double check the SMTP settings and log the results:

```
local r, e = smtp.send{
  from  = USER_SENDING,
  rcpt  = rcpt,
  source  = smtp.message(mesgt),
  server = SMTP_SERVER,
  port = SMTP_PORT,
  user = SMTP_AUTH_USER,
  password = SMTP_AUTH_PW
}

-- Log SMTP results and potential errors
print(r, e)
```

Also, ensure that you're properly chaining your SMTP message using the [LTN12 module](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/ltn12.html) API when it is multipart:

```
  body = ltn12.source.chain(
    ltn12.source.file(io.open("image.png", "rb")),
    ltn12.filter.chain(
      mime.encode("base64"),
      mime.wrap()
    )
  )
```

Or the [Mime module](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/mime.html) API for the EOL:

```
  body = mime.eol(0, [[
    Lines in a message body should always end with CRLF. 
    The smtp module will *NOT* perform translation. However, the 
    send function *DOES* perform SMTP stuffing, whereas the message
    function does *NOT*.
  ]])
```

There is a much more verbose example of this in the [LuaSocket SMTP](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/smtp.html) API documentation.