# how to send email using lua programming language?

Tags: email, lua, gmail, luasocket

Can someone please give detailed explanation on how to send an email using lua, and please share a template.

Should the follow the same procedure to send mail using gmail account? I'm on windows 10 and using lua 5.1.

Scenario: I have a lua function from where I need to send mail to few users. Any help in implementing this will really help.
Thank you.

Comment: what's wrong with the example provided by the LuaSocket documentation? If there is anything you don't understand you should point that out. I mean you tagged your question luasocket, so I guess you already know you can use LuaSocket to send emails right?

Comment: You are right, I was going through luasocket documentation but I did not understand what are the necessary changes I need to make to send an email using the template. Please consider me a novice in lua. @Piglet

Comment: Please guide me with the steps I need to follow to send an email using my gmail account in lua. I'm using lua 5.1 and on windows 10. Any help is really appreciated. @Piglet

Comment: Your question, at the moment is lacking, information of how you have tried to solve this problem yourself. You can try the information in this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49256463/sending-email-with-lua), maybe this will be enough to help you solve your problem

Comment: Sorry about that, finally I could send the mail using luasocket and luasec library. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29312494/sending-email-using-luasocket-smtp-and-ssl)  answer actually what I followed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From: [http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/smtp.html](http://w3.impa.br/%7Ediego/software/luasocket/smtp.html)

> ```
> smtp.send{
>   from = string,
>   rcpt = string or string-table,
>   source = LTN12 source,
>   [user = string,]
>   [password = string,]
>   [server = string,]
>   [port = number,]
>   [domain = string,]
>   [step = LTN12 pump step,]
>   [create = function]
> }
> ```

This describes the function smpt.send which takes a single table as argument.
The fields in square brackets are optional.
Read the docs for details.

The following example shows how to send an email. Notice how the table fields of smtp.send's argument are filled with values. You have to change those values for your use case. Not sure what can be unclear about this.

If you cannot make sense of it as you lack the necessary Lua knowledge I suggest you do a beginners tutorial and read both the Lua Reference Manual and Programming in Lua

> ```
> -- load the smtp support
> local smtp = require("socket.smtp")
>
> -- Connects to server "localhost" and sends a message to users
> -- "fulano@example.com",  "beltrano@example.com", 
> -- and "sicrano@example.com".
> -- Note that "fulano" is the primary recipient, "beltrano" receives a
> -- carbon copy and neither of them knows that "sicrano" received a blind
> -- carbon copy of the message.
> from = "<luasocket@example.com>"
>
> rcpt = {
>   "<fulano@example.com>",
>   "<beltrano@example.com>",
>   "<sicrano@example.com>"
> }
>
> mesgt = {
>   headers = {
>     to = "Fulano da Silva <fulano@example.com>",
>     cc = '"Beltrano F. Nunes" <beltrano@example.com>',
>     subject = "My first message"
>   },
>   body = "I hope this works. If it does, I can send you another 1000 copies."
> }
>
> r, e = smtp.send{
>   from = from,
>   rcpt = rcpt, 
>   source = smtp.message(mesgt)
> }
> ```

Comment: Thank you @Piglet for guiding me, I followed this and then found out google's SMTP mail server will block all the less secure connection and I had to use luasec library for that. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29312494/sending-email-using-luasocket-smtp-and-ssl) answer actually helped me further.